# Suncalc R package - How can I make categorical variables using sunlight times? My logical arguments aren't working

Tags: r, categorical-data, temporal

I have loaded these libraries, not sure if you'll need them all, but will definitely need suncalc.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(suncalc)
```

Here is a list of the first 6 rows of my data. I pulled only necessary columns for what I'm trying to do.

```
structure(list(Date.of.Capture = structure(c(18383, 18393, 18395, 
18395, 18402, 18815), class = "Date"), Month = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 7L), Day = c(1L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 20L, 7L), Year = c(2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2021L), Time.of.Capture = c("6:24", 
"6:27", "8:55", "8:55", "20:22", "6:26"), Time = structure(c(1588314240, 
1589178420, 1589360100, 1589360100, 1590006120, 1625639160), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ToD = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Daytime", 
NA), lat = c(40.75336, 40.75336, 40.75336, 40.75336, 40.75336, 
40.75336), lon = c(-111.624088, -111.624088, -111.624088, -111.624088, 
-111.624088, -111.624088), sunriseEnd = structure(c(1588336111, 
1589199430, 1589372111, 1589372111, 1589976545, 1625659614), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "MST"), sunsetStart = structure(c(1588386056, 
1589250673, 1589423593, 1589423593, 1590028795, 1625713092), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "MST"), dawn = structure(c(1588334143, 1589197398, 
1589370065, 1589370065, 1589974454, 1625657442), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "MST"), dusk = structure(c(1588388024, 1589252706, 
1589425639, 1589425639, 1590030886, 1625715264), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "MST")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L))
```

Here is the code I attempted to run to pull information from my "Time" column and compare it to my "dusk", "dawn", "sunsetStart", and "sunriseEnd" columns for all entries to then place them into categorical variables based on which "Time" the entry occured in. For example, my code attempts to take every value in "Time" column greater than "dawn" column & every value less than "sunriseEnd" column to place it in the "ToD" column as "Dawn" (and continue with all other arguments if untrue).

```
md$ToD<-NA

for(i in 1: nrow(md)){
  if (md$Time[i] > md$dawn[i] & md$Time[i] < md$sunriseEnd[i]){
    md$ToD[i] <- "Dawn"
  } else if (md$Time[i] > md$sunsetStart[i] & md$Time[i] < md$dusk[i]){
    md$ToD[i] <- "Dusk"
  } else if (md$Time[i] > md$dusk[i] & md$Time[i] < md$dawn[i]){
    md$ToD[i] <- "Nighttime"
  } else if (md$Time[i] > md$sunriseEnd[i] & md$Time[i] < md$sunsetStart[i]){
    md$ToD[i] <- "Daytime"
  }
}

unique(md$ToD)
```

Below is code I used to format my columns in a way that suncalc could use them and then created a separate dataframe in which I left joined to the main "md" dataframe.

```
md$Time <- paste0(md$Year, "-", md$Month, "-", md$Day,  " ", md$Time.of.Capture,":00")

md$Time <- ymd_hms(md$Time)

md$Date.of.Capture <- paste0(md$Year, "-", md$Month, "-", md$Day)

md$Date.of.Capture <- as.Date(md$Date.of.Capture, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "MST")

timesofday <- getSunlightTimes(date = md$Date.of.Capture, 
                               lat = 40.753360, lon = -111.624088, 
                               tz="MST", keep=c("sunriseEnd", "sunsetStart", "dawn", "dusk"))

md <- left_join(md, timesofday, by = c("Date.of.Capture" = "date"))
```

After running the above codes, I only get some "Daytime" and "Dawn" outputs, the rest of the entries will show "NA" and what's worse is that the entries that do show "Daytime" and "Dawn" are not even correct. I figured my code should be correct and cannot figure out the issue as to why this calculation using the logical arguments aren't working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on here. Most of your code looks like it would work. Something is weird about the data though. I tried a simple little test: `md$Time > md$dawn`. Those should all be TRUE, but instead this is what I get: `[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE`. No idea what's causing this. Since something is wrong with the values themselves, I'm not surprised the code for `ToD` doesn't work. It's great that you supplied some code and data, but it might be helpful to know the code that created your sample data.

Comment: @JohnPolo I didn't think to even do that. I can provide the code I used to gather this data as well as other columns within my dataset.

Comment: @JohnPolo Hey John, I added some changes that may clarify where errors are. Again, thank you for any help!